# Why doesn't the "select:focus{outline:none}" work?

Tags: css, outline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsRzN.png)

Why doesn't the outline work?

```
select{
    width: 125px;
    padding: 6px 7px;
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
} 
select:focus{
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

is there any other method?

Comment: They are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via `CSS`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: see answer below, definitely not true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is working! you have outline:none !!!

```css
select{
    width: 125px;
    padding: 6px 7px;
    background-color: pink;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
} 
select:focus{
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    outline: green solid 10px;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why is that `outline: green solid 10px;`

Comment: just to show you it's working.  what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm talking about the outline in the selection section